# Need existing user to be able to view data from application using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, console-application

I am making a simple banking application for my computer science class but am not sure how I can store user account details in an array and access it when they sign in. Here is my code.

```
double balance = 0.00;
String name = null;
String menuOptions;
Account[] nameUser = new Account[1000];

System.out.println("Welcome! To create an account please press 1, if existing user press 2.");
Scanner keyboardAccount = new Scanner(System.in);
double a = keyboardAccount.nextDouble();

//If/else prompts user to create account
if (a == 1.0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your full name.");
    Scanner keyboardName = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = keyboardName.next();
    //add this to array of Accounts
    nameUser[1] = new Account();
} else if (a == 2.0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your full name.");
    Scanner keyboardName2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = keyboardName2.next();
    System.out.println("Welcome user " + name + "!");
}
    else {
    System.out.println("Please make an account.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something called **dynamic arrays** so you don't need to know how exact long your array should be

The basic one is called `ArrayList<>`

So in your example code will look like this. Initialize Array

`ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();`

Add users

`users.add(name);`

Retrieve user

```
for(String userFromArray : users){ // Loop over this Array
      if(userFromArray.equals(name)){
            System.out.println("You are signed in!");

            // no need to loop more so break out the loop
            break;
      }

}
```

Hope that I did not misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.